# Ninject request scope and callback

Tags: ninject

I have a problem with Ninject in a MVC project using Owin.

I have a generic class for UnitOfWork that is not specific to my project :

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    public UnitOfWork(DbContext context)
    {...}
}
```

I define two repositories using my custom DbContext :

```
public UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    public UserRepository(MyEntities context)
    {...}
}
public OrderRepository : IOrderRepository
{
    public OrderRepository(MyEntities context)
    {...}
}
```

Then I have a ApiController which use the unit of work and the repositories.

```
public OrderController : ApiController
{
    public OrderController(IUnitOfWork uow, IUserRepository userRepository, IOrderRepository orderRepository)
    {...}
}
```

I configure my Ninject kernel within a module. My bindings are with a request scope.

```
public class MyModule : Ninject.Modules.NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        // Bind all the repositories
        this.Bind(x =>
            x.FromAssembliesMatching("*.Repositories")
                .SelectAllClasses()
                .BindDefaultInterface()
                .Configure(c => c.InRequestScope()));

        // Bind the DbContext of the application
        this.Bind<MyEntities>()
            .ToSelf()
            .InRequestScope();

        // To bind the UnitOfWork, I need to specify the real DbContext to use. For that I use a callback which provide argument to constructor :
        this.Bind<IUnitOfWork>()
            .To<UnitOfWork>()
            .InRequestScope()
            .WithConstructorArgument("context", GetContext);
    }

    private Object GetContext(IContext context, ITarget target)
    {
        IResolutionRoot resolver;
        ActivationBlock scope;

        scope = context.Request.GetScope() as ActivationBlock;
        resolver = scope ?? (IResolutionRoot)context.Kernel;

        var o = resolver.Get<MyEntities>();
        var o2 = resolver.Get<MyEntities>();
        var same = Object.ReferenceEquals(o, o2);
        return o;
    }
}
```

Then I activate Ninject with Owin like this in the Startup class :

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ...
        app.UseNinjectMiddleware(Startup.CreateKernel);

        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        ...
        app.UseNinjectWebApi(config);
    }

    private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Load(new MyModule());
        return kernel;
    }
}
```

It seems good but there is a big problem. The repositories share the same DbContext, but the DbContext in the UnitOfWork is a different instance.
In the function GetContext, the scope is always null, so the MyContext instance is retrieved from the kernel. The boolean variable *same* is always false. The problem is here. The Get function of the kernel return a new instance, instead of the instance of the request scope.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still need this... but you can bind the dbcontext to self and then ask for it when you want to use it.

```
        Bind<ApplicationDbContext>().ToSelf();
        Bind<IUserStoreGuid<User>>().To<UserStoreGuid<User>>().WithConstructorArgument("context", Kernel.GetService(typeof(ApplicationDbContext)));
```

Although the connection string in the app is called "DefautConnection", you need to use "context" because that is how it is called in the constructor argument. I got this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33578999/solution-the-entity-type-applicationuser-is-not-part-of-the-model-for-the-curr/45790790#45790790)