# ASP.NET / Entity Framework - The entity type PartenaireResult is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

I'm new to ASP.NET and can't manage to find any solution nor related thread to my issue.

I want to update an user in database with a onesignal unique identifier via an action method that is getting the current connected User.

I am using database first approach.

I get the following error when launching the request:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type PartenaireResult is not part of the model for the current context.

The thing is that PartenaireResult is not an entity on my table, only a class for returning datas.

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33578999/solution-the-entity-type-applicationuser-is-not-part-of-the-model-for-the-curr) with no luck (only adding another connection string named "DefaultConnection", but I don't understand the concept of NinjectWebCommons.

I also tried to put this coe in my DbContext class with no luck as stated in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688922/the-entity-type-type-is-not-part-of-the-model-for-the-current-context?rq=1):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<PartenaireResult>().ToTable("PartenaireResult");
}
```

Here is the non working method:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "partenaire")]
[Route("api/Partenaires/Me")]
public PartenaireResult GetClientsMe(string onesignal_id)
{
    var connectedUser = GetConnectedUser(User);
    connectedUser.onesignal_id = onesignal_id;

    db.Entry(connectedUser).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();

    return connectedUser;
}

[Authorize(Roles = "partenaire")]
public static PartenaireResult GetConnectedUser(IPrincipal user)
{
    var claimIdentity = user.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    var claim = claimIdentity?.Claims?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type.Equals("IdClient", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

    if (claim != null)
    {
        int idPartenaire;

        if (int.TryParse(claim.Value, out idPartenaire))
        {
            using (var db = new UphairDbEntities())
            {
                var me = db.Partenaires.Find(idPartenaire);

                PartenaireResult PartenaireRes = new PartenaireResult();
                ObjectConverterHelper.CopyProperties(me, PartenaireRes);

                return PartenaireRes;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Here's my `PartenaireResult` class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Web;
using Uphair.EfModel;

namespace Uphair.Api.Models.Partenaire
{
    public class PartenaireResult
    {
        public PartenaireResult()
        {
        }

        public int IdPartenaire { get; set; }
        public string NomComplet { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }
        public PartenaireType Type { get; set; }
        public string Pays { get; set; }
        public string Ville { get; set; }
        public string CodePostale { get; set; }
        public string Adresse { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> Lat { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> Lng { get; set; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        public string CouvertureUrl { get; set; }
        public string TelMobile { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateNaissance { get; set; }
        public bool ADomicile { get; set; }
        public int SeDeplace { get; set; }

        public string IdWallet { get; set; }
        public string IdUserMango { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateAjout { get; set; }

        public string onesignal_id { get; set; }

        public List<NoteItem> Notes { get; set; }

        /**/
        public double NoteGlobale { get; set; }

        public bool Son { get; set; }
        public bool Push { get; set; }
        public string IdPhone { get; set; }
    }

    public class NoteItem
    {
        public int? IdClient { get; set; }
        public string Commentaire { get; set; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        public double Note { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateAjout { get; set; }

        public int Valide { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Any kind of welp would be appreciated.

Thank to anyone who will take the time to read/answer this post.

Comment: The exception come on which line?  What is `ObjectConverterHelper.CopyProperties(me, PartenaireRes);`?  Does is map properties from `me` to `PartenaireRes`?

Comment: Yes, it is doing this. And this is the only line that is using a ```PartenaireResult``` instance. So the exception must come from this line.

Comment: If you map properties manually, does it works?  In your case, I would use AutoMapper.

Comment: Does the partenaireresult reference any types defined in an .edmx?

Comment: @Cygnus Yes, I have a ```PartenaireType``` in my ```PartenaireResult``` that is in my .edmx file.

Comment: @DanielBlais What is AutoMapper ?

Comment: @PierrickMartellière If I were you, try removing those types that are in the .edmx file, and see if the error goes away. I'm willing to bet it does.

Comment: Automapper is great to map entity to DTO (for an example) https://automapper.org/

Comment: @Cygnus, where am I supposed to put the ```PartenaireType``` ? It's part of my Partenaire class, how can I replace it ?

Comment: I tried to put it in my Api's Models directory, but I can't access it with using in my EfModel.

Comment: I used ```Partenaires.Find()``` in another action controller instead of and everything worked well. Thanks to all !

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of this problem is the DbContext (the "UphairDbEntities" instance) doesn't have the 'PartenaireResult' type.

1. First, I would de-collapse the .edmx file in your project and find the "....tt" file and expand it. You should see a "..cs" file for every table that you included in your edmx file.
2. Make sure there is a "PartenaireResult.cs" file there

If the file is not there, one of two things is happening:

1. You have a second .edmx file (maybe that you deleted before creating this one) that already has a "PartenaireResult.cs" file. Delete that file (if it exists), open up and re-save your .edmx file to regenerate the "PartenaireResult.cs" file as part of your project.
2. Your PartenaireResult.cs is not part of the .edmx, so your UphairDbEntities context doesn't have a PartenaireResult type.

This problem can frequently happen when you're using multiple contexts that share a table. If Entities1() and Entities2() both reference the same table 'Table1', then only one of those Contexts will have the table.  One workaround for this issue is to rename the mapped tablename in one .edmx; the second workaround is to only keep the table in one context.

Comment: I think you're right. Will tell you tomorrow. Thanks for your interest !

Comment: Thanks for your well explained answer. However, I don't see how I can resolve my issue with your informations. The ```PartenaireResult``` class is only used for returning purpose, it's not an Entity and it's not in my edmx. It never was. I don't understand the last part of your answer, and precisely the solution you're proposing to me.